# How do I handle duplicate strings in Android to reduce memory usage?

Tags: android, string, optimization

I just started using the Memory Analyzer Tool (MAT) to see if I can optimize my Android app. It displays weather data obtained from XML files from the internet. I'm seeing a large number of Duplicate Strings because of the obvious repeat of certain weather-related strings ("clear", "partly cloudy", etc.).

What would be the most efficient way to reduce memory overhead with such similar strings? Enumerate the most common strings and match them during the XML parse operation?

thanks.

Comment: You can always put them into enums but I have doubts would it help or make your program less stable. Getting these strings on as-is basis from fetched xml sounds the most reasonable way to do this for me.

Comment: In a word, yes! :)  Create an enum on your class which represents the weather and set a corresponding "condtions" variable.  e.g.  if(node.toString().equalsIgnoreCase("clear"){weather.conditions = Conditions.Clear;}

Comment: Thanks for the ideas. I will probably take a small subset of the most used strings and enum them and see if anything changes. Based on the comments so far, I'm getting the general sense that even though MAT makes a big deal of duplicate strings and memory usage, it's not really that big of a deal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [String.intern()](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html#intern%28%29).
But I doubt you can reduce memory footprint by removing duplicate strings